# How to deploy a MS Teams bot?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to build a bot for MS Teams in order to use the Graph API do to things like removing participants from a conversation.

I followed [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/AudioVideoPlaybackBot) Microsoft sample bot but got stuck on the deployment stage which requires **Azure's cloud service**. Is there a better way for deploying the bot and maybe a way for debugging it? In similar samples, the instructions are vague and confusing.

Comment: Please use below docs to deploy the code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, so the best I can do is give you direction, rather than specific answers. In that case, the following should be helpful:

1. In terms of samples, the one you've linked is very specific, and might be confusing to understand - I would suggest starting with more generic "bot" samples to get a better understanding. It's worth noting that bots for Teams use the standard Microsoft "Bot Framework", so not -all- samples are applicable for Teams, but have a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples

It looks from your profile that you code in python, so note that the link above includes Python samples too.

2. With regards runtime, bots for Teams do need to be registered with the central Microsoft Bot Framework service, which is indeed linked to Azure. However, it's not at all required to *host* your bot in Azure - the bot is basically just a web REST endpoint, listening for messages - it can be hosted on any web-address (httpS) endpoint. In that case, you would look in Azure for a "Bot Channels Registration", which is just the registration part, without hosting. A "Web Bot" in Azure, for example, is a combination of the registration as well as a hosting model in Azure.

As I said, it's a broad question, but hopefully the above gives some useful starting points.

Comment: @Ami- Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT It did not help, what would help is a working and current example, maybe with local deployment.

Comment: @Ami-Could you please refer the below document for Cloud Service:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy-portal#:~:text=1%20Concepts.%20The%20cloud%20service%20definition%20file%20%28.csdef%29,Install%20Azure%20SDK%20to%20open%20the%20Azure%20